# Geometry: Isosceles Triangle, Line Drawn, Pr

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

The image above is given. *D* is found on side *BC* of the isosceles triangle *ABC*. *G* is the continuation of the line *AB*. Given: 
*BC* || *FE*.  Given: $\frac{GF}{BF}$ = $\frac{AG}{AC}$ . Prove: *AE* $\perp$ *BC*.

My question is: Is the proportion necessary? Is it possible to just say that because $\triangle$ *ABC* is isosceles, then *D* is the midpoint of side *BC* etc.?

How can one solve this?

Comment: Not given any angle or equality like $BD = DC$, without the given proportion, how can you conclude that $D$ is the midpoint?

Comment: I guess not. I wasn't sure if one could assume that a line from the vertex of an isosceles triangle necessarily bisected the line opposite.  I think you are correct. So, how can one solve this problem? (I'm assuming it uses the proportion, but I don't know how).

Comment: The proportionally information can be used to prove that $AE$ bisects $\angle GAC$

Comment: How does one do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\triangle FGE \sim \triangle BGC\\
\frac {GF}{BF} = \frac{GE}{EC}\\
\frac{GE}{EC} = \frac{AG}{AC}\\
\frac {EC}{AC} = \frac{GE}{AG}$

$\frac {EC}{AC} = \frac{GE}{AG} \implies AE$ bisects $\angle GAC$

Comment: I understand that the triangles are similar. Can you please explain how you came to all of the proportions?

Comment: As in, I don't understand how in your first proportion, you got GC over EC. Shouldn't it be GE over EC?

Comment: I also don't understand how, in your second proportion, you got AC in the denominator of the second ratio? I got GF.

Comment: How do you prove that AG/AC = GC/EC? (Aside from using numbers)

Comment: Regarding the 2nd line, you are correct, and i have fixed it above.  Regarding the 4th line.  Why does $\frac{GE}{EC} = \frac {AG}{AC} \implies \frac{EC}{AC} = \frac{GE}{AG}?$  Multiply both sides of the first equation by $\frac {EC}{AG}.$

Comment: I understand how you got from the second proportion to the third. I don't understand how you got the second proportion.

Comment: In other words, how did you get that GE/EC = AG/AC?

Comment: It is given that $\frac{GF}{BF} = \frac {AG}{AC}$ and from the line above we found that $\frac{GF}{BF} = \frac{GE}{EC}$ by the transitive property then $\frac{GE}{EC} =  \frac {AG}{AC}$

Comment: Beyond thanks. The letters are so confusing.